# How to return array from element-wise calculation on two different arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, square-root

I have the following two numpy arrays of n elements:

```
A = np.array([2 5 8 9 8 7 5 6])
B = np.array([8 9 6 5 2 8 5 7])
```

I would like to obtain array C:

```
C = np.array([sqrt(2^2+8^2) sqrt(5^2+9^2) ... sqrt(6^2+7^2)])
```

That is, array C would consist of n elements; each element would be equal to the square root of the square of the respective element in A plus the square of the respective element in B.

I tried using `np.apply_along_axis` but it seems that this function is designed for one array only.

Comment: Why not use vectorized ufuncs : `np.sqrt(A**2 + B**2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you can use:

```
C = np.sqrt(A**2 + B**2)
```

Or you can use `comprehension` and `zip`:

```
C = [sqrt(a**2 + b**2) for a, b in zip(A,B)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your arrays are huge in size, consider using `np.square` instead of `**` operator.

```
In [16]: np.sqrt(np.square(A) + np.square(B))
Out[16]: 
array([  8.24621125,  10.29563014,  10.        ,  10.29563014,
         8.24621125,  10.63014581,   7.07106781,   9.21954446])
```

---

The difference in execution times are very minimal though.

```
In [13]: ar = np.arange(100000)

In [14]: %timeit np.square(ar)
10000 loops, best of 3: 158 µs per loop

In [15]: %timeit ar**2
10000 loops, best of 3: 179 µs per loop
```